# Obtain and update textbox value from URL attributes in Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I currently have a bokeh_app.py file deployed and running absolutely fine
It is accessed by anyone in the network via URL  HostName:PortNumber/bokeh_app

I want to add code which will make the app work via following URL
HostName:PortNumber/bokeh_app/?textboxvalue

And the page that would open is HostName:PortNumber/bokeh_app with updated Text box value to textboxvalue from the URL

What would be the changes I need to make to my code to achieve this, if possible. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing HTTP request arguments is covered in the documentation:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#accessing-the-http-request